# Slideshow - images out of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a little website with a slideshow under my navbar and experimenting with flexbox.

So i want that this slide show is "responsive", in the sense that when I modify my browser width and height only the div's width increase (not the heigth). This is the structure of my slideshow:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1901x630"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1902x630"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1903x630"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1904x630"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1905x630"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.slideshow{
background-color: firebrick;
height: 350px;
}

.slideshow ul{
position: relative;
}

.slideshow ul li{
opacity:0;
position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7j5zpx14/1/

I've tried using flexbox but I didn't figure out whats wrong with this divs and images.

Comment: Set min height rather than height. For ex..slideshow{min-height: 350px;}

Answer (score 0):

You cad only below css in **img tag** and see [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7j5zpx14/2/)

Css:

```
.slideshow img {
  float: left;
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

see  [Fiddle Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/7j5zpx14/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually didn't thought could be that easy the solution...